# Are there DFS Diagnostic Utilities server and client

Tags: dfs, diagnostic

Are there any tools for DFS troubleshooting? Some searches suggest network monitoring, but if you dont know how to read the scans with DFS in mind it seems a bit pointless.

Comment: I've deleted my "inappropriate" answer. If you list what troubleshooting step/s you have already tried and the result/s thereof, then perhaps a more "appropriate" answer will be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a lot of investigation it turned out the problem was "Pismo File Mount Audit Package" version 51.

Removing this fixed the problem!

Using Safe Mode+Networking identified this - although this kind of fix is getting harder and harder to do. Note to dev, use the error logging facilities!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have some inactive root server or link.

Use dfsutil.exe  with /pktinfo switch to list down details of DFS root and verify all root and link servers are online.

some good articles on DFS

http://blogs.technet.com/filecab/archive/tags/DFS+Namespaces/default.aspx

[DFSutil syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779494%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Youve got the tool *Distributed File System* under Start -> programs -> Administrative Tools.
If you dont have it (for example on Windows XP) you can download the administration tool pack from microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en

With the tool you can at least check the status (is the server and share online).

Please clearify what exactly you want to monitor or troubleshoot. Are you experiencing some dfs related issues? There are a few key points to check:

1. DNS (is the forward/reverse lookup for the used dc's,servers and clients correct)
2. Does a firewall block port 445 (tcp) or some other AD related ports?
3. Are the file permissions on the DFS root set correctly? (a directory on the dc is created for every target you define)

Comment: The problem is, that from my machine(XP) a DFS share is not behaving correctly. Its slow to open the root, the files below the root usually fail to open and a message about "You might not have permission..." in the same dialog is says "A device attached to the system is not functioning" - no clue as to what device and why. Works fine from another machine though

Comment: Hi.

Sounds odd. Did you try it with the same user at a different machine?
Please double check the permissions on the DFS Targets, File Shares and File Systems.

Did you check your user account in AD? Maybe the password is expired or the account is locked out.
Also check if the computer account in the AD is still ok.

Check if the "Service Routing and RAS" is activated and running (i hope its named like this ive only got a german windows xp at home)

Comment: Same User Different Machine  = No problems. Diff user same machine = same problem :-( Safe Mode + Networking = DFS works fine. Just cant work out which device is loaded and would effect DFS interactions....